# Does Child Class Inherited their parent class prototype in the following example (JS)

Tags: javascript, class, oop, inheritance, prototype

the follwoing code:

```
class Rectangle {
    constructor(w, h) {
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
    }
}

Rectangle.prototype.area = function () {
  return (this.w * this.h);  
};

class Square extends Rectangle {
    constructor(w, h) {
        super(w,  h);
        // this.w = w;
        // this.h = h;
    }
}
```

Do I have problems with my inheritance?

I'm trying to use:

```
const rec = new Rectangle(3, 4);

const sqr = new Square(3);

console.log(rec.area());

console.log(sqr.area());
```

`rec` prints the correct answer but `sqr` print's out: `NaN`

I also tried maybe adding a Square prototype:

```
Square.prototype.area = function () {
  return (this.w * this.w);  
};
```

but the output is:

```
-1  
-1
```

so this also affected area for `rec.area()`

Comment: Square does not have a `h`. this.w * undefined will be NaN

Comment: "*Do I have problems with my inheritance?*" At a higher level, you have [the square-rectangle problem](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238176/why-would-square-inheriting-from-rectangle-be-problematic-if-we-override-the-set). But specifically in your case, you're just not setting `h`. Just because a rectangle has four equal sides, doesn't mean it doesn't have a height. I just means the height is equal to the width.

Comment: @Tushar Shahi still, the same problem remains I did try this before posting also I tried to override it somehow but the parent prototype overrides my Square.prototype

Comment: After the edit, you have a Square constructor that takes two parameters. But you only pass one argument. So, `h` is implicitly `undefined`.

Comment: @VLAZ I don't have control over how many var I'm passing I only have control over Rectangle Square implementation

Comment: Right...so if you want to pass only one argument, you need a constructor with one parameter...

Comment: @VLAZ I also tried this before, same issue

Comment: @VLAZ I believe the problem is with the .area prototype .. not sure when I extend the Rec do I also get the area method with it .. I tried looking in MZD no ans

Comment: Let me give you one last hint - a rectangle has a two pairs of sides, each of them equal to each other. A square, has four equal sides, which is the same as `h = w`. So, if you only get *one* side's length, how do you construct a rectangle where `h = w`? "* not sure when I extend the Rec do I also get the area method with it*" if you didn't have the method, you'd get an error that you cannot call it. Since you *can* call it, it's there.

Comment: Thanks I used it to solve it but @trincot gave me new info about prototype notation .. thanks both of you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `Square` constructor will be called with only one argument (since its size is equal at all sides), you need to "translate" this to a `Rectangle` constructor call that needs 2 arguments (width and height). Since both are equal for the square, you need to pass that single argument twice to the `Rectangle` constructor:

```js
class Rectangle {
    constructor(w, h) {
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
    }
    area() { // Use this notation for prototype methods
        return this.w * this.h;  
    }
};

class Square extends Rectangle {
    constructor(w) { // One argument...
        super(w, w); // ...Two arguments, but width == height
    }
}

let square = new Square(10);
console.log(square.area());
```

Comment: I was able to solve it by doing this:
```java    class Square extends Rectangle {
        constructor(w, h) {
            super(w, h);
            this.w = w;
            this.h = w;
        }
        
    }```
why does this work ?
also does your new area() notation equals the one I wrote ?

Comment: That also works, but it is a pity that you first set `this.h` *wrong* (by calling `super` with a second argument that is undefined), and *then* must correct that error by yet another assignment to `this.w` and `this.h`... I see no good reason why you would do it this way.

Comment: Yes, the new `area()` notation equals yours. Since ECMAScript 2015 this is the way you use the `class` notation to the full.